# gurobi.GRBException: No Gurobi license found

Tags: java, eclipse, gurobi

I'm recently using gurobi(java) in eclipse, I'm sure I have successfully got a license and everything was fine when I used gurobi to solve LP problems like that:

```
public LP(int n, int[]s, int[][]b) throws GRBException
{
    ...
    env = new GRBEnv("LPRelaxation.log");
    model = new GRBModel(env);
}
```

Then I added a QP part to my program and the error occurs:

```
public QP() throws GRBException
{
    env = new GRBEnv("LPRelaxation.log");
    model = new GRBModel(env);
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" gurobi.GRBException: No Gurobi license found (user asus, host OWEN-ASUS, hostid fccf6a77)
at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:20)
at methods.QP.<init>(QP.java:16)
....
```

Comment: There is not much we can do here, except for leading you to [the official docs on license-checks](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_mac/testing_your_license.html) (i just linked some mac-based doc; search the docs for your OS).

Comment: It seems that I was using `env=new GRBEnv()` too many times so it caused a problem, now I've changed it and it works again, thx!

Comment: Now the problem is clear: I didn't use `env.dispose()` after I finish using the Gurobi environment. This way I may open too many environments and cause a problem. The official doc is [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/java_grbenv_dispose.html).

Comment: Typically, you should use one Gurobi environment (GRBEnv object) per program. You can have multiple models (GRBModel objects) for a single Gurobi environment.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! I didn't think of this way before, and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

set the environment variable GRB_LICENSE_FILE with the path to license key file

reference:
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_mac/testing_your_license.html